# In Mist, does setting up a different datadir necessarily mean it runs on a testnet?

Tags: mist, testnets, datadir

I'm running Mist on Windows, and I want to change the datadir because I'm running out of space on the C drive, but I want it to be on the actual Ethereum blockchain.

Will I run into trouble if I change the datadir?

Comment: No, you can simply change the datadir to whatever you like. Do you know how this is done in mist?

Comment: To change it in Mist, first run geth with the --datadir flag, and then launch Mist. (They both need to be running)

Comment: To set datadir in Mist: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/how-to-set-a-different-datadir-in-mist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you are free to change the data directory. It's just a place to store the blockchain, it doesn't mean that you would be on a different chain.

Comment: but does mist allow the --datadir flag?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the datadir, by using `--datadir` is all OK.

Running Geth on the testnet is a different flag, `--testnet`.

**If you've been using Geth and have ether in your accounts, don't forget to backup all your keystore files before deleting the old datadir.**

Comment: why do you mention geth here if the question is referring to mist?

Comment: @knocte Here's the question on setting Mist's datadir http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/how-to-set-a-different-datadir-in-mist and it also ends up at Geth...