# Importing wallet into Mist using custom datadir

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mist, wallets

I'm having an issue that seems to be quite common but I haven't found a solution. I'm using Ethereum Wallet 0.9 and I have all the application data, including the blockchain on an external drive. When I want to launch the wallet I first launch geth and point it to where the latest blocks are (on the drive in the chaindata subfolder of the Ethereumwallet.exe). This works fine and geth starts from the latest block I have, and when I open Ethereumwallet it talks to geth and shows only the latest blocks need to sync.

However, Ethereumwallet.exe doesn't see my keystore (stored in the same directory) and also doesn't let me import my json wallets when pointing geth to my directory. When I start Ethereumwallet without configuring datadir, it starts downloading the entire chain but does show me my wallets and my existing balance. How to import my wallet files by default and have a custom datadir?

Comment: On linux you can launch EtherWallet with argument (so you just go ./etherlaunch --datadir "pathtodatadir" --keystore "pathtokeystore"). I don't know if you can do that on windows too.

Comment: Or you can follow the instruction here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/how-to-set-a-different-datadir-in-mist?rq=1